# GAE restricted class error when connecting to SQLite database

Tags: java, sqlite, google-app-engine, jdbc, jetty

I am writing a web application using Eclipse Neon, GWT and sqlite. My webapp at a certain point connects to a database located in the `war` directory (necessary in order to make the db available to the server). When I try to create the connection, strictly in read mode:

```
Properties config = new Properties();
config.setProperty("open_mode", "1");
Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");
return DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:db.db");
```

The following exception stack occur in the console:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: java.io.FileOutputStream is a restricted class. Please see the Google  App Engine developer's guide for more details.
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.agent.runtime.Runtime.reject(Runtime.java:52)
at org.sqlite.SQLiteJDBCLoader.extractAndLoadLibraryFile(SQLiteJDBCLoader.java:165)
at org.sqlite.SQLiteJDBCLoader.loadSQLiteNativeLibrary(SQLiteJDBCLoader.java:290)
at org.sqlite.SQLiteJDBCLoader.initialize(SQLiteJDBCLoader.java:65)
at org.sqlite.core.NativeDB.load(NativeDB.java:53)
at org.sqlite.core.CoreConnection.open(CoreConnection.java:211)
at org.sqlite.core.CoreConnection.<init>(CoreConnection.java:76)
at org.sqlite.jdbc3.JDBC3Connection.<init>(JDBC3Connection.java:24)
at org.sqlite.jdbc4.JDBC4Connection.<init>(JDBC4Connection.java:23)
at org.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.<init>(SQLiteConnection.java:45)
at org.sqlite.JDBC.createConnection(JDBC.java:114)
at org.sqlite.JDBC.connect(JDBC.java:88)
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
[...]
```

I'm actually just opening a connection towards the database. Logs are forwarded to console, so no file was open to store them, and I don't create files. The error originates from GAE and the JDBC loader, on which I have no control.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will answer my own question... and the answer is, I didn't need GAE, so I had to disable it. I removed all GoogleAppEngine jars from war/WEB-INF/lib and disabled AppEngine by navigating on Eclipse:

```
RightClick on project -> Google -> AppEngine Settings... -> detick "Use Google AppEngine"
```

Hope it helps someone else.